# How to update a Vue component props object from outside?

Tags: vuejs2

I need to update the `props` object of a Vue component from outside Vue. I have a solution which seems to work but I get a warning that I want to get rid of.

I create a Vue compoent like this:

```
    this.vm = return new Vue({
      render: h => h(component, {
        props: propsData,
      })
    }).$mount(el);
```

Then in a function I update the props from outside Vue as follows

```
    this.updateProps = function (props) {
       const children = this.vm.$children;
       const firstChild = children && children[0];
       if (!firstChild) {
         return;
       }
       _.each(_.keys(firstChild.$props || {}), (key, i) => {
         firstChild.$props[key] = props[key];
       });
    }
```

This works, but I get the this warning message:

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "xxxx"`

How should this be done correctly, without getting a warning?

Comment: Suggestion: Since you're talking about Vue components being affected by outside resources (i.e. plain JS functions), try a different approach like using a global JS event bus to achieve the same effect. E.g. external JS function emits an event via the event bus. Your Vue component is listening to the same event bus and receives the event and does things accordingly. For the bus, you can enhance it with 'channels' and 'payloads' to keep things organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. As in that warning, create your own data in component and use the props as initial value, or use computed property.For example:

```
props: ['initialCounter'],

data: () => ({
  counter: this.initialCounter
})
```

Or:

```
props: ['size'],

computed: {
  normalizedSize () {
    return this.size.trim().toLowerCase()
  }
}
```